# Variables are not retained after using wait command with a function in BASH

Tags: bash, function, variables, wait

I have to log measurements from a variety of sensors, some of which take quite a while. I want to obtain the readings from the sensors simultaneously in order to save time.

I have a function, *foo*, that reads some sensors and saves the values as variables, e.g. a variable called *bar*.

I am using the **wait** command to pause the script until the foo function is finished prior to making a HTTP get to send all the measurements to a server for logging.

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    bar=$(command for reading sensor here)
    echo "bar is $bar"
}

foo & #this is to run the foo function as a background process.

temperature=$(command for measuring temperature here)
humidity=$(command for measuring humidity here)

wait %1 #this should pause the script until the function foo is complete.
echo "function foo has finished. bar is $bar"

curl -X GET -G (URL to server) -d bar=$bar -d temperature=$temperature -d humidity=$humidity
```

When I run the script, the output is as follows:

> bar is 1234
>
> function foo has finished. bar is

Note that this **should** say "function foo has finished. bar is 1234".

...if I add in set -x at the start of the script, the curl command (at the end of the script) ends up looking like this:

> curl -X GET -G (URL to server) -d bar= -d temperature=21.5-d humidity=65

Again, note that the *bar* variable is empty.

If I have the same script without the **wait** command (and run the function without the ampersand after it), the function correctly sets the *bar* variable, and the resulting curl command is complete. However, when I use the wait command as above, the variables from the *foo* function are lost once the function has finished.

Is there some way of retaining these variables that are set by the function *foo*?

Comment: When you execute a command in the background, it's in a subshell process, so none of its variable assignments are in the main shell.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `wait` command, it's just the ampersand.

Comment: You can have the function write the value to a file, then read the file after `wait`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that explanation. Is there a way of setting it to a variable held in memory instead of writing it to a file though? I'm trying to reduce disk writes as much as possible as this will be a very remote IoT device so I want to maximise device longevity as much as possible...

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, never mind. I just remembered I have a file in a tmpfs partition that I already read and write data to anyway. I'll just use that. :)

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarising Barmar's comment here so it can be marked as an answer...

The issue is that the function running in the background is run in a sub-shell, rather than the same shell that the main script is running in, and the variables that are set in the sub-shell are never transferred into the main shell (in which the script itself is running).

A possible solution is to write the variables to a file and - after the wait command - read the variables from those files again.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer in a few days when SO will allow me to, unless someone else provides a better answer.